# shell scripting for jenkins

Tags: shell-script, shell

My Jenkins environment variable `$SVN_URL` is `http://project/svn/neslrepo/trunk/java_project`. I want to extract `java_project` and store in a variable through my shell script.

I tried:

```
job_name=(echo $SVN_URL | awk -F "/" '{print $NF}')
echo $job_name.war
```

I expected the output to be `java_project.war`, but it didn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7):

The shell [already provides](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html) some nice tools to do this, no need for an external command:

```
$ SVN_URL="http://project/svn/neslrepo/trunk/java_project"
$ echo ${SVN_URL##*/} 
java_project
```

So all you need is:

```
job_name=${SVN_URL##*/}.war
```

Answer (score 3):

It appears that `basename` can also do this, despite the argument being an HTTP URL instead of a filesystem path.

```
echo $(basename "http://project/svn/neslrepo/trunk/java_project/").war
java_project.war
```

Since the man page does not mention HTTP URLs, this is probably an abuse of `basename`. It seems to be a side effect of the structural similarity between an HTTP URL and a filesystem path. `man 3 basename` says (emphasis mine):

> The functions dirname() and basename() break a null-terminated
>   pathname string into directory and filename components. In the usual
>   case, dirname() returns the string up to, but not including, the final
>   '/', and **basename() returns the component following the final '/'.
>   Trailing '/' characters are not counted as part of the pathname.**

Answer (score 2):

I tried by below 2 methods and it worked fine

```
Method1

@praveen_linux_example ~]# SVN_URL=http://project/svn/neslrepo/trunk/java_project
[root@praveen_linux_example ~]# jobname=`echo $SVN_URL| awk -F "/" '{print $NF}'`
[root@praveen_linux_example ~]# echo $jobname.war
java_project.war
======================================================================================================
Method 2

 SVN_URL=http://project/svn/neslrepo/trunk/java_project
@praveen_linux_example ~]# echo $SVN_URL| sed "s/.*\///"| sed "s/$/.war/"
java_project.war
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your `job_name=(echo $SVN_URL | awk -F "/" '{print $NF}')` line.

You are trying to use **[command substitution](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/commandsub.html)**, however, you've forgotten the `$`.

It should be the following in order to make bash execute the commands in brackets:

```
job_name=$(echo $SVN_URL | awk -F "/" '{print $NF}')
```

The following snippet worked perfectly for me:

```
#!/bin/bash

SVN_URL="http://project/svn/neslrepo/trunk/java_project"

job_name=$(echo $SVN_URL | awk -F '/' '{print $NF}')
echo $job_name.war
```